# issue with ffmpeg config

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos

a ffmpeg was installed in my server but it no support some liberary like libvpx
(centos 6.5)
I couldn't uninstall it but I install I new one with this tutorial:
http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFMpeg+Installation+on+CentOS+and+RedHat#FFMpegInstallationonCentOSandRedHat-InstallLibvpx

(all configs in ffmpeg seems install correctly)

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" \ 
--extra-libs=-ldl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac \
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay \
--enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads
```

So I want to  test it:

I try test it with:

```
 #ffmpeg
```

result:

[image]

It seems related with older ffmpeg that was install.
no change and no lib add!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your PATH settings; best is to use the full path to the newly built binary:

```
$HOME/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: A big Thanks...but whats the address for shell_exec("$ffmpegPath -i $inputPath $outPath"); in php?  I think /url/bin/ffmpeg but It dosen't work

Comment: for sure "/url/bin" would have to be "/usr/bin" but you'll have to find out $HOME by typing in `echo $HOME` on the commandline that you used to compile

Comment: Finally I found it but get sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied

Comment: looks like you compiled and installed it as `root` but the OS tries to execute `ffmpeg` under the permissions of the privileged user that runs the web server; you'll probably need to install in to a different directory that is accessible for user `www-data` or whatever user your OS/distribution uses to run the web server, see: https://superuser.com/questions/455935/php-script-cant-run-bash-script-sh-permission-denied